# How to make a Discord Bot perform a certain action each specified weekday?

Tags: python, python-3.x, asynchronous, time, discord.py

I am currently working on a slightly complex discord bot that performs certain actions based on data in my MySQL DB. One of these actions is applying and deleting specific ranks.
Another function that I want to implement is that the bot posts a specified message to a certain channel eg. each monday. The time actually is important therefore I am having trouble on evaluation how long my async functions need to sleep before posting the message.

The Posts of the bot are enabled/disabled by another set of commands.

```py
from discord.ext.commands import Bot, is_owner

bot = Bot('!')

global PostData
PostData = False
global DataSet
DataSet = False

@is_owner()  # Only bot owner can run this command
@bot.command()
async def PostData_enable(ctx, *, q):
  global PostData
  PostData = True

@bot.command()
async def PostData_disable(ctx):
  global PostData
  PostData = False

@bot.command()
async def DataIsSet(ctx):
  global DataSet
  DataSet = True


@bot.event
async def on_ready():
  await timerfunction()

async def checkDataSet():
  global DataSet
  if DataSet = False:
    await asyncio.sleep(20)
  else:
    DataSet = False
    return True

async def timerfunction():
  global PostData
  if PostData:
    if datetime.date.weekday() == 0:
      # execute the following function always at 12:00
      postMessageMonday() # I have excluded this function since
                          # it is not relevant for my question
    elif datetime.date.weekday() == 9:
      # execute the following function always at 19:30
      postMessageSunday()
      # as soon as DataSet = True execute this
      testanswer = await checkDataSet()
      if testanswer:
        postAnotherMessageSunday()
  await asyncio.sleep(30) # I need to be able to change this value
  await timerfunction()


bot.run("token")
```

Since I can not guarantee that the bot is always started/stopped at the exact same time I want to be able to adjust the value of the `await asyncio.sleep()`-function. Another problem is that I do not know when the Data that I wanna include into my message is set. Therefore the `checkDataSet()`- function can take an unknown amount of time. But I want to be able to start the loop of `timerfunction()` always on at the same time.

Comment: You should be able to achieve something like this using [the background task](https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py/blob/master/examples/background_task.py).